# What do scriptures say about aligning with unrighteous people for righteous cause?

Tags: scripture, dharma

For a dharmic cause can one align with a known unrighteous person if the latter happens to be in favor of this particular cause. Please note that in general the unrighteous person goes against dharma but for this cause the person is on-board. However his underlying motivations are unknown and neither does one know if for the unrighteous person achieving this cause will be an intermediate victory for a different cause he/she is pursuing.

Comment: Samudra manthan can be taken as one of the example where Devata seek help of Asura and Danava.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto - Good point. Any dialog between devatas on this very point before samudra manthan? i.e. if it is okay to take help of asuras ?

Comment: There is no mention of conversation which would have happened between Devata and Danava in Vishnu Purana, Refer: [Book 1, Chapter IX](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp044.htm#page_70)

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto - I meant among devatas . If they contemplated on aligning with daitayas. But from VP it seems they didn't and followed instructions of Lord Vishnu.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto - But we can't extend that to today's world as Lord Vishnu is not giving direct instructions

Comment: Why not? Shastras are there to guide us, we should use our intellect then. In fact bhagwan Krishna said that our first Guru is our intellect because it knows what is right or what is wrong.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto - I believe dharmashastras say that one's own intellect is the last resort

Comment: And would you not use it when needed like the situation mentioned in question? :)

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto - That's why i specifically asked what are the scriptures saying. If scriptures are silent on it then will have to resort to intellect. :-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Divide & Conquer in scriptures?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/30052/divide-conquer-in-scriptures)

Comment: @sv - thanks. It is quite close. While my question is on dharmic cause, your answer seems applicable when one is pursuing artha. but if there is nothing else will accept it as duplicate

Answer (score 2):

In the *Uddhava Gita* XVI.19-20 (Swami Madhavananda translator), Sri Krishna says:

> 19. By ascribing worth to sense-objects a man comes to be attached to them; from attachment arises the desire for them; from attachment arises the desire for them, and desire leads to dispute among men.
> 20. Dispute engenders vehement anger, which is followed by infatuation. Infatuation quickly overcomes his hitherto abiding consciousness of right and wrong.

These preceding verses echo the *Bhagavad Gita* verses II.62-63.

and in *Uddhava Gita* XXI.3, Sri Krishna says:

> One should never associate with evil persons, who are solely after satisfaction of their animal instincts. One who follows a single one of them falls into abysmal darkness, like a blind follower of the blind.

Comment: Hi. Can you please recheck XX.3. Chp 20 is on gunas. And verse 3 is something else. https://estudantedavedanta.net/Uddhava%20Gita-Madhavananda.pdf

Comment: @Carmensandiego yes, typo. I have corrected. It is XXI.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

During Samudra Manthan, Bhagavan Vishnu gives the analogy of a snake, rat & hunter, to Devas when discussing whether to shake hands with Asuras temporarily.

When a snake gets caught in a hunter's net, it asks it's janma-virodhi (rat) for help to gnaw away the net, assuring it of future safety. When rat gnaws off the net, the snake escapes then pounces on the rat.

There is a similar story from the rat's perspective. Where a cat gets caught in a net, and there is a owl on the tree waiting to eat the rat. The rat makes friends with the cat, asking for protection both from the owl (cat's enemy) and the cat itself. The cat agrees. But the smart rat doesn't gnaw off the entire net, for fear the cat would break its promise. Only when the hunter arrives, it gnaws off the final loop of rope, giving the cat just enough time to escape the hunter, and the rat just enough time to escape into a hole.

Heard this in upanyasam, don't have online textual source.

Comment: Welcome back ! Good answer. I will try to find source for this.